# Subclassing PFUser does not effect the data stored

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

### I am using Swift.

### This question talks about the Parse service.

I've read ways using both the `@NSManaged` and `dynamic` key-words, so I decided for my example to implement them both. The issue here is that in the `User` object of my data manager, I'm noticing that additional information is not being stored in the database. For my application I would like to store some additional information in the User table, such as their first and last name. Here's an example:

```
import Parse

public class User : PFUser {

    @NSManaged public var firstName: String!
    dynamic public var lastName: String!

    override public class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    init(email: String, password: String) {
        super.init();
        self.username = email;
        self.email = email;
        self.password = password;
        self.firstName = "MyFirstName";
        self.lastName = "MyLastName";
    }

}
```

Here's the code I'm using to initialize and send off the data:

```
@IBAction func register() {
    let newUser = User(email: "myemail@provider.com", password: "my password");
    newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("Success")
        } else {
            print(error);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** Upon playing around in the dashboard it seems like fields that are added to the User table / document / whatever you want to call it in a schema less database are automatically removed. This would indicate that I would need to create another class (IE: UserInfo) to store all of the users information, such as first and last name. Is this correct? If so that seems a little odd, as it would increase the amount of requests to login to the application. (One for validation, one for retrieving information). Is this the correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding properties to a subclass won't them automatically added to the `PFUser` instance. You will have to use the `PFObject` methods to set the properties and then save the `PFUser` object.

The [Parse Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-signing-up) gives an example of setting an extra `phone` property on the `PFUser` instance before calling signup. This is how you can add the `firstName` and `lastName` properties to `PFUser`.

Comment: Right, I misunderstood, one thing I've noticed while subclassing is that you cannot use `addObject` or it will crash the application, you must instead use `setObject` if the variable name is the same as the key. This is not explained in the documentation (to my knowledge)